# How to send custom Email in Azure Data Factory using Azure Function and Web activity

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I want to use Azure function app and create a function to send the custom Email using Outlook. Then using this function url, post the Email subject, Body, sender list using Azure Data Factory Web activity so that during any failed/success criteria I can send the corresponding Email from the Azure Data Factory.
Note that I want to do this through function apps only and not through the Logic Apps. I know the Logic apps is the standard way but I want to do it through the Azure Functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SendGrid bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=csharp). Here is the [code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid?tabs=csharp#attributes-and-annotations). To make this code work, you need to sign up, create apikey, create a sender and verify your identity [here](https://sendgrid.com/).

Comment: Thanks Steve. I will check this option. But is there direct way to use a function in HTTP function and use that inside the ADF without using the SendGrid?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no direct way to achieve this.